# JAVA 8: сумма цифр часов и минут в 24-часовом формате

Tags: java, дата

Как подсчитать сколько раз сумма цифр количества часов и минут в 24-часовом формате `ЧЧ:ММ` была ровно 14 (если ограничиться временным диапазоном с 11:45 до 22:30)?

Примеры:

```
17:51 ( 1+7+5+1 = 14)
1:38  ( 1+3+8 = 14)
```

Думаю, что нужно использовать LocalTime:

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("17:51");
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse("21:38");

int hour, min, sum, count=0;
for( ; time1.isBefore(time2); time1 = time1.plusMinutes(1)){
    hour = time1.getHour();
    min = time1.getMinute();
    sum = hour/10 + hour%10 + min/10 + min%10;
    if(sum==14)
        count++;
}
```

Comment: с чем возникла проблема? Самый прямолинейный способ - тупо перебрать все варианты.

Comment: Запустил Ваш вариант. Вроде работает :)

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("17:51");
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse("21:38");

int hour, min, sum, count=0;
for( ; time1.isBefore(time2); time1 = time1.plusMinutes(1)){
    hour = time1.getHour();
    min = time1.getMinute();
    sum = hour/10 + hour%10 + min/10 + min%10;
    if(sum==14)
        count++;
}
```